# Memory footprint and performance of IORef

Tags: haskell, ioref

I wonder what is the memory footprint of a variable from type IORef a if I know that the size of a is x.
Also what is the expected performance of the function writeIORef applied to integer compare to say a regular variable assignment  (like x = 3) in,  say, Java ?

Comment: By using `IORef`, you make use of a reference, so it is  "*boxed*", making it not efficient. But I think you somehow want to write imperative programs in a functional language. That will usually not give the requested performance. Like they sometimes say "*Haskell does not solve a different set of problems, it solves the same problems differently.*".

Comment: This is my goal fast doubly-linked list in Haskell. Sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Haskell, an `IORef a` behaves like a single-element mutable array. The [definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IORef.html#IORef) of `IORef` is the following, disregarding newtype wrapping:

```
data IORef a = IORef (MutVar# RealWorld a)
```

Here, `MutVar# RealWorld a` is a primitive mutable reference type. It is a pointer which points to two words, a header, and a payload which is itself a pointer to a normal lifted Haskell object. Hence the overhead of `MutVar` is two words (16 byte on 64 bit systems) and one indirection.

The overhead of `MutVar#` is thus one extra indirection and one extra header word. This is unavoidable. In contrast, the overhead of the `IORef` constructor is also one header word and one indirection, but it can be eliminated by unpacking `IORef`:

```
data Foo a = Foo !(IORef a) a a
```

Here, the bang on `IORef` causes the underlying `MutVar` to be unpacked into `Foo`. But while this unpacking works whenever we define new data types, it does not work if we use any existing parameterized type, like lists. In `[IORef a]`, we pay the full cost with two extra indirections.

`IORef` will be also generally unpacked by GHC optimization if it is used as an argument to a function: `IORef a -> b` will be generally unboxed to `MutVar# RealWorld a -> b`, if you compile with optimization.

However, all of the above overheads are less important than the overhead in [garbage collection](http://blog.ezyang.com/2014/05/ghc-and-mutable-arrays-a-dirty-little-secret/) when you use a large number of `IORef`-s. To avoid that, it is advisable to use a single mutable array instead of many `IORef`-s.

Comment: Note that the `!` annotation only implies strictness, not unpacking.  You need to compile with `-funbox-strict-fields` or use an `{-# UNPACK #-}` pragma on individual strict fields to actually unpack them.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr that's not right, since GHC 7.8 or so word-sized strict fields are [automatically unpacked](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-optimisation.html#ghc-flag--funbox-small-strict-fields).

Comment: Oh, thanks!   I guess I've been writing a lot of unnecessary `{-# UNPACK -#}`s.